# Manipulating files in java

Tags: java

I would like to read multiple txt files and play an output file after the code interaction.
how do I pass the files to the code? are three .txt files

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
      int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]), i;
      if(n <= 0) return;

      String narq[] = new String[n];
      for( i = 1 ; i <= n;i++)
        narq[i - 1]= args[i];
        Merge(n, narq, args[n + 1]);
    }
    static void Merge(int n, String [] narq, String exit1) throws
    IOException{
    BufferedReader in[] = new BufferedReader[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        in[i] = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(narq[i]));
    BufferedWriter out;
    out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(exit1));
  }
}
```

Comment: my error code is.. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at TestandoArquivo.Principal.main(Principal.java:8) line 8 is int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]), i;

Comment: I'm putting the following java code on the command line "java Main1 file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt.

Comment: Strange that you're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception there. What IDE are you using, if any? Also, why are you trying to parse an integer from a string?

Comment: are three txt files each with a number in each line the code has to read these files and sort the numbers and return a single file with the numbers ordered.

Comment: I'm using eclipse

Comment: Parsing an integer from your arguments won't do anything in that regard. Your `args` array should be `{"file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"}` based on your sample command line input. The easiest way to read from a file is to use a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). There are tons of articles online about it if the documentation isn't enough.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than manipulating files you've put more work into manipulating the **args[]** String array. You don't really have to do this, instead utilize the fact that you have this variable. All you should have in your **main()** method is:

```
if (args.length == 0 || args.length < 2) {
    return;
}
Merge(args);
```

and that's all, just pass the **args[]** String array to your **merge()** method which of course will need to be slightly modified. What do these code lines above do?

In the **if** statement the condition `args.length == 0` is checked first and if true then this means that no Command Line arguments were passed to the application and therefore we exit the **main()** method with a ***return*** statement which ultimately 
closes the application.

If however the first condition passes (there are Command Line arguments) then the `|| args.length < 2` condition is checked and if there were less than two arguments (file names) provided then again, we jump out of the **main()** method and exit the application. We need at least 2 file names to carry out any sort of file merge (a ***Source File Name*** and a ***Destination File Name***). In your application the last argument within the Command Line is always to be considered the ***Destination File Path/Name***. All other files listed within the Command Line will be merged into this file.

The last line is of course the call to the **merge()** method which does all the work. Because the call is from within the **main()** method the **merge()** method will need to be a **static** method and it might look something like this:

```
/**
 * Merges supplied text files to a supplied single destination text file.<br><br>
 * 
 * @param args (1D String Array) All elements (file paths) within the array are 
 * considered files to be merged to the destination file with the exception of 
 * the very last array element. This element must contain the destination file 
 * path itself. Two or more file paths must be provided within this array 
 * otherwise no merging takes place.<br>
 * 
 * @param overwriteDestination (Optional - Boolean) Default is true whereas the
 * merge destination file is always overwritten if it exists. If false is supplied 
 * then the destination file is not overwritten and merging files are appended to 
 * the existing data within that destination file.
 */
public static void merge(String[] args, boolean... overwriteDestination) {
    boolean overwrite = true; // Default - Overwite Destination file if it exists.
    if (overwriteDestination.length > 0) {
        overwrite = overwriteDestination[0];
    }

    try ( // PrintWriter object for last file name in args array
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[args.length - 1], !overwrite))) {

        // BufferedReader object for files in args array (except the last file).
        BufferedReader br = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++) {
            File f = new File(args[i]);
            if (!f.exists() || f.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("The specified file in Command Line named " + 
                                    args[i] + " does not appear to exist! Ignoring File!");
                continue;
            }
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String line;
            /* Loop to copy each line of the file currrently
               in args[i] to the last file provided in args 
               array (last file name in command line)   */
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                pw.println(line);
            }
            pw.flush();

            // close reader;
            br.close();
            System.out.println("Merged " + args[i] + " into " + args[args.length - 1] + ".");
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger("merge() Method Error!").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger("merge() Method Error!").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Modify the method to suit your needs if desired.

Answer (score 2):

Recommend to use java.nio package. Here is the working code, update as required:
Run with arguments such as  - c:\a.txt c:\b.txt c:\c.txt

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.LinkOption;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class Appender
{
    private static String outFilePath = "c:\\merged.txt";

    private static boolean needLineBreakAfterAppend = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            // handle
            System.out.println("No input files provided, return without doing anything");
            return;
        }
        Path destFilePathObj = Paths.get(outFilePath);
        if (!Files.exists(destFilePathObj, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
            Files.createFile(destFilePathObj);
            System.out.println("created destination file at " + outFilePath);
        } else {
            System.out.println("destination file at " + outFilePath + " was existing. Data will be appended");
        }
        Arrays.asList(args).forEach(filePathToAppend -> merge(filePathToAppend, destFilePathObj));
    }

    private static void merge(String filePathToAppend, Path destFilePathObj)
    {
        boolean fileExists = Files.exists(Paths.get(filePathToAppend));
        if (fileExists) {
            System.out.println("Input file was found at path " + filePathToAppend);
            try {
                // Appending The New Data To The Existing File
                Files.write(destFilePathObj, IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileReader(filePathToAppend)),
                    StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                System.out.println("Done appending !");

                if (needLineBreakAfterAppend) {
                    Files.write(destFilePathObj, "\n".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                }

            } catch (IOException ioExceptionObj) {
                // handle it
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Input file was NOT found at path " + filePathToAppend + ". Return without appending");
            // handle it
        }
    }
}
```